# Erro de "interpret 8-bit bytestrings" no SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7

Estou iniciando com o SQLAlchemy e me deparei com este erro:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytes
trings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like
text_factory = str). 
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings. 
u'INSERT INTO algoritimo ("nomeAlgoritimo", classe, "estruturaDados", "complexidadePiorCaso",
"complexidadeMedioCaso", "complexidadeMelhorCaso", "complexidadeEspacos", "pseudoAlgoritimo") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' 
('Ordena\xe7\xe3o Sele\xe7\xe3o', 'Algoritmo de oderna\xe7\xe3o', '
Array, Listas ligadas', 'O(n^2)', 'O(n^2)', 'O(n^2)', 'O(n) total, O(1) auxiliar', '')
```

### Código

```py
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///classificacao_pesquisa.db')

class Algoritimo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'algoritimo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nomeAlgoritimo = Column(String(50))
    classe = Column(String(250))
    estruturaDados = Column(String(50))
    complexidadePiorCaso = Column(String(50))
    complexidadeMedioCaso = Column(String(50))
    complexidadeMelhorCaso = Column(String(50))
    complexidadeEspacos = Column(String(50))
    pseudoAlgoritimo = Column(String(4000))
```

Como posso setar o *charset* `('utf-8')`?
Versão do Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabalhar com Unicode utilize:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __ future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```